# What is exactly the loss value evaluated at every epoch of training?

Tags: neural-network, keras

If I compile a certain model with adam optimizer and I have used a batch size of 32 in the fit function, When I start training the model, I get a loss value at the end of every epoch. I understand that the gradient of the loss function is computed through a mini-batch, and hence, the weight updates are done through each batch. Now, what is the loss value evaluated at the end of every epoch when I train the model , is it the loss value evaluated at the end of the last batch in the training set ( last step per epoch), or is it the loss value evaluated for the whole dataset at the end of the epoch ? Or Is it for example the mean of losses per each batch? I am using `tf.keras` package